# declare variable, then initialize it in a try/catch?

Tags: php

I would like to be able to use `$conn`  in different functions inside my page, but because I initialize it in a try/catch, I receive warnings saying the variable is not initialized. How is it possible to declare it, then initialize it in the try/catch ?

This does not work :

```
global $conn; // or $conn = null; + $this->conn in the next line
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
```

---

EDIT :
Here is a new attempt : a warning says container is not initialized :

```
$res = $container->db()->query($sql);
```

The new code :

```
<?php  
    class Container {

        public function db(){
            $host = "localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $pass = "root";
            $dbname = "test";
            static $conn = null;
            if (!isset($conn)){
                try {
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    echo 'connected to db';
                    return $conn;
                } catch(PDOException $e){
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            return $conn;                
        }
    }

    $container = new Container();

    function query($sql){
        $t = microtime(true);
        try {
            $res = $container->db()->query($sql);
            if ($res){
                printf( "%0.2f ms : %s", (microtime(true) - $t)*1000, $sql);
                return;
            }
        } catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    query("SELECT * FROM Animal");
```

Comment: Have you heard of IoC containers before maybe? If not, it seems like a perfect fit for this use case.

Comment: `global $conn` does not make a variable global, rather it means use the global version of this variable. So you would initialize `$conn` in global scope and call `global $conn` in different scopes when you want to set or access it. This is not an answer because you **should not** do it this way. You should redesign the code to avoid this situation.

Comment: can you write your full code & from where you are calling that. if you are calling that inside a function then you should use global $conn inside the function.

Comment: @dan08 would you have a solution?

Comment: Yea, the additional code helps.

Comment: @jewelhuq I edited my post

Comment: @N.B. I edited my post

Comment: You are making things complicated. Instead of writing your code in such a way i would recommend you to use redbeanphp. if you dnt know write me i will teach or even i will write the whole code you wrote. just message me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yea, your already using a class. Its just needs little redesign. 
I would suggest moving query() into the class, but up to you.

Here is a very simplified example;

```
class Container(){
  protected $conn = null;

  //I would have a constructor, but up to you
  public function __construct(){
    $this->db(); //this will set $this->conn
  }
  public function db(){
    try{
      $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
      $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

  public function getConn(){
    if( ! $this->conn ){
      $this->db(); //set $this->conn
    }
    return $this->conn;
  }

  public function anyFunctionInYouClass(){
    //you now have access to the connection opbject with $this->conn
    $this->conn->query(); //orwhatever
  }

}

function outsideClass(){
  $db = new db();
  $db->getConn()->query();
}

//OR

//Good if you are using $db in many functions
$db = new db();
function outsideClass($db){
  $db->getConn()->query();
}
```

This is far from a working example but hopefully the idea is clear.

Sidenote: Don't mix static and instance variables

Comment: actually, I did not want to have the `$db` in the parameter, but instead initialize it outside the function and use it in the function. Would you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Yea, using `global $db` in the function will work, but what wrong with having it as a parameter